# Vuetify v-carousel run function after transition

Tags: vuetify.js, v-carousel

Is it possible to run a function after a transition in the v-carousel?

I want to show some percetage numbers in my v-carousel and when the v-carousel changes I want that the numbers count from 0 to (e.g.) 97%. So that the user is focussed on exactly this number.

Is there any possible solution how I can run a function in a v-carousel-item after the transition?

Thanks and best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself. Here the answer. In the v-carousel task I v-model(ed) the item of the carousel and every time the item changes, the watcher will start an action.

```
...
    <v-carousel v-model="currentIndex">
      EXAMPLE CONTENT
    </v-carousel>
...

...
currentIndex: 100
...


watch: {
  currentIndex: function() {
    DO SOMETHING
  }
}
```